# TextArea in Tabs component in antd UI Toolkit and text not getting rendered

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using [antd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd) with [React](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react) and have the following code:

```js
<Tabs  type="card">
  <TabPane tab="Summary" key="1">
    <TextArea name="Name" 
              rows={4} 
              style={{marginBottom: '10px'}} 
              defaultValue={"DefaultValue"}/>     
  </TabPane>
  <TabPane tab="Description" key="2">
    <TextArea name="Name" 
              rows={4} 
              style={{marginBottom: '10px'}}           
              defaultValue={"DefaultValue"}/>
  </TabPane>
</Tabs>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

In the defaultValue props I am rendering values from props. But only the second text area renders the value I send from props and the first TextArea remains blank. If I set value instead of defaultValue it works but I can't edit the text inside it. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Two things here - to be able to edit the `value`, you need to implement the onChange handler, and update the state of the component. Second, you should name the textAreas differently (currently they both have the same name).

Per [official Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values):

> In the React rendering lifecycle, the `value` attribute on form elements will override the value in the DOM. With an uncontrolled component, you often want React to specify the initial `value`, but leave subsequent updates uncontrolled. To handle this case, you can specify a `defaultValue` attribute instead of value.

With that said, making your Components controlled mean implementing the `onChange` handler, and setting their `state`.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      first: "First Default Value",
      second: "Second Default Value"
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Tabs type="card">
          <TabPane tab="Summary" key="1">
            <TextArea
              name="first"
              rows={4}
              style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}
              value={this.state.first}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </TabPane>
          <TabPane tab="Description" key="2">
            <TextArea
              name="second"
              rows={4}
              style={{ marginBottom: "10px" }}
              value={this.state.second}
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </TabPane>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3y04o5ml0m)

Comment: I know how to make it with onChange. The point is that i want to set defaultValue on both of them and when I switch to see it and to be able to edit. At this point only the second tab renders the defaultValue text and the first one doesn't. Thanks.

Comment: Here's your exact code https://codesandbox.io/s/2wyrjjvrzy which works. I can't recreate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can't edit the text inside it because you don't have an `onChange` handler.

You can read about the difference between `value` and `defaultValue` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).